# Datatables(angularjs) stop working correct to after editing/adding/deleting a table row

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using Datatables with angularjs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datatables)

When I **add, edit or delete** a row in the table, Datatables stop to function correct(sorting, paging, search, info, etc). I use **push** to add data rows on the table, **splice** to remove from table...

Here is some of my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'datatables']
    , ['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    }]);
    
app.controller('UserGroupsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $sce, $timeout) {
    $scope.groups = [];
    $scope.group = {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            description: ''
        };
    $scope.edit_group = {
            index: '',
            id: '',
            name: '',
            description: ''
        };
    
    //Load Groups
    $scope.loadGroups = function () {
        $http.get('/groups/ajax')
            .then(function success(e) {
                $scope.groups = e.data.groups;
            });
    };
    $scope.loadGroups();

    //Create Group
    $scope.createGroup = function () {
        $http.post('/groups/ajax', {
            name: $scope.group.name,
            description: $scope.group.description
        }).then(function success(e) {
            $scope.groups.push(e.data.group);
        }, function error(error) {
        });
    };

    //Update Group
    $scope.updateGroup = function () {
        $http.patch('/groups/ajax/'+$scope.edit_group.id, {
            name: $scope.edit_group.name,
            description: $scope.edit_group.description
        }).then(function success(e) {
            $scope.groups[$scope.edit_group.index] = e.data.group;
        }, function error(error) {
        });
    };
    
    //Delete Group
    $scope.delete = function (index) {
        $http.delete('/groups/ajax/'+$scope.groups[index].id)
            .then(function success(e) {
                $scope.groups.splice(index, 1);
            });
    };
}]);
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="UserGroupsController">
<table datatable="ng" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="dataTable">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Options</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr class="odd gradeX" ng-repeat="(index, x) in groups">
              <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ x.description }}</td>
              <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="edit(index)">Edit</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(index)">Delete</button>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: It seems to me you mix angular DataTables for angularjs and angular together.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What I might doing wrong..

Comment: `[dtOptions]` is angular notation; `dtTrigger` only exists in DT for angular +2. The rest seems to be pure angularjs ~1.

Comment: thank you for that, I have replaced `[dtOptions]` with `dt-options="dtOptions"`, but still facing the same issues